# Jenkins - Build job monthly or weekly

Tags: syntax, jenkins, cron

What is the cron syntax for scheduling a Jenkins job:

a) monthly
b) weekly

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Jenkins provides a helpful overview here. If you tick on *Build periodically* in the job configuration, you can click on the question mark next to *Schedule*.

I just want to quote one small part of it (it's always helpful to read the entire help yourself):

> This field follows the syntax of cron (with minor differences).
>   Specifically, each line consists of 5 fields separated by TAB or
>   whitespace:
>
> ```
> MINUTE HOUR DOM MONTH DOW
>
> MINUTE Minutes within the hour (0–59)
> HOUR   The hour of the day (0–23)
> DOM    The day of the month (1–31)
> MONTH  The month (1–12)
> DOW    The day of the week (0–7) where 0 and 7 are Sunday.
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> In addition, @yearly, @annually, @monthly, @weekly, @daily, @midnight,
>   and @hourly are supported as convenient aliases. These use the hash
>   system for automatic balancing. For example, @hourly is the same as 
>   `H * * * *` and could mean at any time during the hour. @midnight 
>   actually means some time between 12:00 AM and 2:59 AM.

Comment: I configured my build like this 31 11 * * 1-6 which 11:31 AM every workday. I don't see the build running under the build history but I ran and appeared in build history after finishing, Do I need to do some other config so that its visible while running?

Comment: You didn't hyperlink your first sentence.

Answer (score 8):

Jenkins also supports predefined aliases to schedule build:

@hourly, @daily, @weekly, @monthly, @midnight

@hourly --> Build every hour at the beginning of the hour --> 0 * * * *

@daily, @midnight --> Build every day at midnight --> 0 0 * * *

@weekly --> Build every week at midnight on Sunday morning --> 0 0 * * 0

@monthly --> Build every month at midnight of the first day of the month --> 0 0 1 * *

Answer (score 3):

For weekly I successfully use: H 0 * * 0